# How do I negate a matcher in top?

Tags: salt-stack

As I understand it, I can match a set of specific minions in top like this:

```
base:
  '^(someserver|thingy|broken)$':
    - match: pcre
    - state_to_apply
```

Which will apply `state_to_apply` to the minions 'someserver', 'thingy', and 'broken'.

How do I apply a state to everything *except* those three minions?

How do I do the same for a nodegroup?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "negative lookahead" of regular expressions for this:

```
base:
  '^(?!(someserver|thingy|broken))$':
    - match: pcre
    - state_to_apply_if_not_match
```

This can be used both in top files and in the node group definition.

You can also [use the `not` operator](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/compound.html) when defining a node group or selecting nodes in a top file. The documentation lists `'* and not G@kernel:Darwin'` and `'* and not web-dc1-srv'` as examples.

AFAIK you can't negate a node group in the top file. You'll need to define a second node group with the negated expression.